# In a multi-account AWS environment, how would I force a role assumption on a IAM user when he/she logs in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am managing a multi-account AWS environment with consolidated billing. At the same time, I centralize all IAM user creation under one alias (account) for effective management. But their resources reside in other AWS accounts which are created on project basis.

I have set up the delegated Access across AWS accounts using IAM roles and it works. However these users need to switch role manually every time they log on. It is cumbersome. How could I force these users to acquire such role automatically when they log on ?

Comment: This is working as designed for cross account role access. Why not create the groups in the account they use most frequently? Currently to my knowledge there is no real solution if they need console access to different accounts.

Comment: I am the only person to manage the set-up so my goal is to achieve multiple objectives in one shot : (1) centralize the user management (2) have billing breakdown by project (3) each user logging into their native environment without too much hazzle

Answer (score 0):

You can provide them with the link to directly log into that account that they consider "native". If they are not logged into the base account AWS will force a log into that account, then switch role automatically.

> You can manually construct the link yourself by using the following format:
>   https://signin.aws.amazon.com/switchrole?account=account_id_number&roleName=role_name&displayName=text_to_display
>   Where your administrator provides the account_id_number and role_name to you. For text_to_display, see the explanation in step 5 in the following procedure.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html